# exact area resampling

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I do image processing, and right now I need to resample some images taken from slightly different perspectives so I can match up features. The pixel intensities have scientific significance, so I want to do something that will preserve local flux and not "miss" anything. What I want to do is exact area resampling, as discussed here:

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-261.pdf

Except the coordinate change I'm doing is not just a translation; at the very least it involves translation, rotation, and perspective change.

I can't find anything on file exchange or by googling. Any ideas?

Comment: This is best addressed by the dsp stack exchange site. 